# Removing rows based off of duplicate answers in different columns

Tags: r

I have a data.frame `test`that looks like the following:

```
> test <- data.frame(X=c(1, 3, 2, 1), Y=c(2, 2, 1, 3), Z=c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
> test
  X Y Z
1 1 2 A
2 3 2 B
3 2 1 C
4 1 3 D
```

I want to be able to remove any row where there is an un-ordered duplicate pair. More specifically, where in the first row `X = 1` and `Y = 2`, it's un-ordered duplicate pair is found on the 3rd row where in this instance `X = 2` and `Y = 1` -- I'd like to remove the either entry of the two. The resulting data.frame should look like:

```
> final.test
  X Y Z
1 1 2 A
2 3 2 B
4 1 3 D
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194611/extracting-unique-combination-rows-from-a-data-frame-in-r) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028369/removing-duplicate-combinations-in-r-irrespective-of-order)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/15487151/1191259 which leads to `test[, c("X","Y")] <- with(test, list( pmin(X,Y), pmax(X,Y) )); test[!duplicated(test[, c("X","Y")]),]`