# Select pair-wise duplicated rows [A-B & B-A]

Tags: r, subset

I have an input input matrix

`df <- data.frame(a = c(1,1,2,4,3,5,2,1,1,3), b = c(4,3,3,1,2,2,4,4,4,2), d = LETTERS[1:10])`

I want to get

```
out <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,4,3,1,1,3), b = c(4,3,1,2,4,4,2), d = c(A,C,D,E,H,I,J))

#   a b d
# 1 1 4 A
# 2 2 3 C
# 3 4 1 D
# 4 3 2 E
# 5 1 4 H
# 6 1 4 I
# 7 3 2 J
```

I want to extract any rows that are duplicated in both columns – also in reverse order

I tried `df[duplicated(df[c("a")]) | duplicated(df[c("b")]) ,]` but it does not work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a duplicate, but it's pretty close to several other questions.  The only difference from the more common case is that you want to keep the non-unique rows rather than remove them, which is just a matter of negation.  E.g. [Extracting unique combination rows from a data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194611/extracting-unique-combination-rows-from-a-data-frame-in-r) or [pair-wise duplicate removal from dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297812/pair-wise-duplicate-removal-from-dataframe).  There are a variety of other questions in a similar vein.

Answer (score 2):

You can group the data frame by rowwise sorted columns `a` and `b` using `pmin` and `pmax` of column `a` and `b`, and then filter based on the condition that the group contains at least two rows:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
       group_by(pmin(a,b), pmax(a,b)) %>% 
       filter(n() >= 2) %>% 
       ungroup() %>% 
       select(a,b,d)

# Source: local data frame [7 x 3]
# 
#       a     b      d
#   <dbl> <dbl> <fctr>
# 1     1     4      A
# 2     2     3      C
# 3     4     1      D
# 4     3     2      E
# 5     1     4      H
# 6     1     4      I
# 7     3     2      J
```

Comment: And a base R equivalent (or at least similar approach) might be `dfDups <- with(df, cbind(pmin(a,b), pmax(a,b))); df[duplicated(dfDups) | duplicated(dfDups, fromLast = TRUE), ]`

Answer (score 1):

In base R you could use `duplicated` together with `apply`:

```
df[(duplicated(df$a)&duplicated(df$b))|
   apply(df,1, function(l) sum((l[["a"]]==df$b)&(l[["b"]]==df$a))>0),]

   a b d
1  1 4 A
3  2 3 C
4  4 1 D
5  3 2 E
7  2 4 G
8  1 4 H
9  1 4 I
10 3 2 J
```

Comment: `base R` (i.e. your sollution) appears to be faster!!! My microbenchmarks with the data provided show that your solution is almost 4 times faster than the `dplyr` solution.

Answer (score 0):

One can also use pairwise max and min (pmax and pmin) to override the order and then find the duplicate rows from first and last, and merge the two results. Albeit a long solution , it might be of interest:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,1,2,4,3,5,2,1,1,3), b = c(4,3,3,1,2,2,4,4,4,2), d = LETTERS[1:10])

out <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,4,3,1,1,3), b = c(4,3,1,2,4,4,2), d = c('A','C','D','E','H','I','J'))    


mx<- with (df, pmax(a,b))
mn<- with (df, pmin(a,b))

df2<- data.frame(mx, mn)
df2

a<- df[duplicated(df2),]
b<- df[duplicated(df2,fromLast = T),]

res<- merge(a,b,all = T)
res<- res[order(res$d),]

res 
out

#check
sum (as.character(res$d) !=as.character(out$d) )
```